В сигнатуре метода параметр базового класса, а в вызове функции наследники
Есть класс Product и его наследники (один из них, WashingMashine). Нужно в классе-обработчике (условно третий класс, Processor) написать функцию getOptimProductByPrice, которая принимает и обрабатывает и Product, и его наследников.
Как это сделать?
Наследник:
public class WashingMashine extends Product {...}```

обработчик:
ArrayList<Product> commonOrder = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<WashingMashine> washingMashines = new ArrayList<>();

WashingMashine wm = getOptimProductByPrice(washingMashines);

public Product getOptimProductByPrice(ArrayList<Product> products){//действия}


Сейчас возникает логичная ошибка, что нужно заменить тип wahingmachines с ArrayList< Product> на ArrayList < WashingMashine >

Тип параметра объектов листа поменять нельзя, либо используй обобщенный тип, либо напиши адаптер для списка объектов . Разные типы списков передавать параметром нельзя. Можешь почитать тут, если столкнешся с проблемой полиморфизма наследуемых классов.

Используй
public Product getOptimProductByPrice(List<? extends Product> products)

